# How to keep lock a cell value even if the condition changed?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

please refer to the images below

[Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDDDe.png)
[sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mgnv.png)
I have 2 sheets: sheet1 and sheet2, here's what I want to do: if sheet2!B37 = sheet1!B1, take the value of sheet1!B2, if not stay blank.

This part is easy, but what I want is that if I change the date in sheet1!B1 to 16 Mar 2021 and sheet1!B2 to 90, I want sheet2!C37 to stay 100 and sheet2!C38 returns 90.

Comment: Please share your sample sheet.

Comment: I think you need scripts to change values in the way you described as sheet can't refer to values that are no more present in your spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to copy the content of sheet2!C37 and paste it as value.

**Reference:** [Convert formulas to values in Google Sheets](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2019/04/11/google-sheets-convert-formulas-values/)

But I doubt that you would want to convert the formula into a value every time you need to change the condition. Hence, you might want to consider using Google Apps Script and run it using a button.

### Sample Code:

```
function updatePrice() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //Get Sheet1 object
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  //Get Sheet1 object
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");

  //Get Sheet1!B1 string value
  var targetDate = sheet1.getRange("B1").getDisplayValue();
  //Get Sheet1!B2 string value
  var targetPrice = sheet1.getRange("B2").getDisplayValue();

  //Get Sheet2 column B range
  var dates = sheet2.getRange("B1:B");
  
  //Create a textfinder and look for the target date (Sheet1!B1 value)
  var textFinder = dates.createTextFinder(targetDate);
  var firstOccurrence = textFinder.findNext();

  if(firstOccurrence!=null){
    //Date found
    //Update price in column C
    firstOccurrence.offset(0,1).setValue(targetPrice);
  }
}
```

### What it does?

1. Get the active spreadsheet using [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivespreadsheet)
2. Get the sheet object for `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` using [Spreadsheet.getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)
3. Select the range for `Sheet1!B1` and `Sheet1!B2` using [Sheet.getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation). Get the string value using [Range.getDisplayValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalue)
4. Select the range for `Sheet2!B1:B` using [Sheet.getRange(a1Notation)]
5. Create a textFinder using [Range.createTextFinder(findText)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createtextfinderfindtext)
6. Get the first occurrence of the date string that was being searched using [TextFinder.findNext()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#findnext). If date string has no match, return will be `null`. If date string has match it will return a [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) of the matching cell
7. Matching cell will give you a range in `column B`, to set the price value move the range 1 column to the right by adding `1 column offset` using [Range.offset(rowOffset, columnOffset)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset) and set the range value using [Range.setValue(value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)

---

### [Add A Google Sheets Button To Run Scripts](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-sheets-button/)

1. Add a Google Sheets button. You add a button via the Insert > Drawing menu.
2. Click Save and Close, this drawing gets added to your Google Sheet. You can right click on it to resize it or drag it around to reposition it.
3. To assign a script, Right Click the drawing and click the three little dots in the top right of the drawing and select Assign Script. Then type in the name of the function you want to run from your Apps Script code.

[image] [image]

---

### Output:

[image]

> **Note:**
>
> Please don't forget to click enter when editing your Sheet1 values before clicking the button. Apps Script cannot update Sheet2 when the cell to be read is still in edit.

[image]

Comment: Hi Ron, thank you for the detailed explanation! I've tried the script, it said "Finished Script" but it doesn't update the price. Here's a sample sheet I created, mind take a look for me please? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WG7uxV9g7l67-vYA00Avn8cN4BIBQSjDMoe_85XG1Fg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi @beaniemeanie, the reason why it was not updated is because your Sheet1!B1 date format doesn't matched with the Sheet2!B date format. As mentioned in the answer provided we are using text finder to search for a specific string within a range of date value in Sheet2!B. To fix your problem, you can change the format of Sheet1!B1 in Format tab -> Number -> More Formats -> More date and time formats -> Select 5 Aug 1930 format

Comment: I modified your sample sheet and verify that it is working. If we answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)